# How Do You Prevent Raw HTML from Rendering in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get my Vue.js app to render raw html instead of the code itself.

The code from the server looks like this:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;
```

But when it gets render, the html code get interpreted as text instead of code

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

I've tried using v-html, decodeURIComponent, and a filter but no luck:

Is it possible to fetch escaped code from the database and render it as raw html in Vue.js?

Comment: Show us how you tried v-html, please.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it inside a v-html

```
<span v-html="here_your_html"></span>
```

**update**

I see your problem is about escaped content.. Try with a method: `unescape(your_html)`;

like:

```
<span v-html="unescape(here_your_html)"></span>
```

and in your methods:

```
unescaunescapepeS(string) {

  //create an element with that html
  var e = document.createElement("textarea");
   
  //get the html from the created element
  e.innerHTML = string;

  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Here a sanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-curran-116fm?file=/src/App.vue

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As your HTML is being loaded from the server, you'll need something like **`v-runtime-template`**. Here is the example to start with.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-runtime-template :template="template"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    template: `
      <app-title>Howdy Yo!</app-title>
      <vue-router to="/croco-fantasy">Go to the croco-fantasy</vue-router>
    `
  }),
};
</script>
```

`v-runtime-template` automatically gets the context of the parent component where it’s used and then it uses a dynamic component to let Vue compile and attach. Here is the complete [Article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/v-runtime-template/) about it.